# Portuguese Stack Overflow top bar dropdown contains English

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, localization, portuguese-stackoverflow

Go to [Stack Overflow in Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) and expand the StackExchange dropdown menu that is found on the top left of the screen.

Provided you are not logged in already, you will see the words

> Sign up or log in to customize your list.

in the middle of what is an otherwise localized menu.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed as of last night!

[image: Portuguese all over]

Comment: "Faça Sign up" looks weird. Fixed on transifex (BTW, is it possible to get a direct link to a specific string there?)

Comment: @bfavaretto I'd check, but for whatever reason I can't log into Transifex...

Comment: @bfavaretto I checked, and yes. At least for me, the url changes for whatever string you're currently seeing.